# Boot into windows directly (not windows boot manager)/Editing the windows BCD from linux?

Tags: windows

I was editing the boot entries in windows boot loader and deleted the windows entry by mistake, after the restart there seems to be no way to get into windows to add the entry back. ANY help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found your answer by now. I know it's possible to fix it from a Linux distro, but I don't know how yet.

Here's what I do know: From Windows XP and forward, perhaps prior to XP, there is a restore feature in the CD or DVD in the Windows Installation disk. If your PC doesn't have a CD/DVD-ROM or you don't have a disc, you can use Microsoft's media creation tool with a USB drive.

Then run either the disk or the USB - make sure USB boot is enabled in BIOS/UEFI and that it has first priority. Then run the installer and then look carefully for "repair" or "repair tools". Windows 10 has an automated repair tool, but it doesn't always fix an issue. Hopefully you have backed up BCD files. If so, you can use those to repair Windows' boot configuration.